# Using @Value with condition in spring in order to map value to string

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-properties

I have a application.properites file with the following:

```
xxx.xxx = sandbox
xxx.sandbox = 123
xxx.production = 456
```

I would like to map to a string value 123 in case xxx.xxx == sandbox and 456 in case xxx.xxx == production

```
...
public class temp { 

 @Value("${??????}")
    private String token;
}
```

is it possible to fill in a condition incited of the ?????? that will map the token to 123 or 456 according to xxx.xxx ?

Comment: Use profiles instead, loading the appropriate property files for each.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple way in case someone will hit this question:

```
@Value("#{'${xxx.xxx}'=='sandbox' ? '${xxx.sandbox}' : '${xxx.production}'}")
```

I just think it is much easier that start working with profiles.

Comment: Aweswome! I was missing the quotes around the inner '${xxx.xxx}'

Answer (score 4):

You can use Spring Profiles, so you can have a property file for each enviroment.

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application
>   configuration and make it only available in certain environments. Any
>   @Component or @Configuration can be marked with @Profile to limit when
>   it is loaded

You can see more here
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: after i'm using the above profile technic, how should i map the xxx.sandbox or xxx.production according to the profile from the application.properites file?

Comment: What kind of application are you running ? You can use this property -Dspring.profiles.active=production" at the moment you run the application

Comment: OK, but these profile can help you to map the beans for spring, how i can use it to map in case of profile x  use xxx.production, in case of profile y use xxx.sandbox?

Comment: You can use something like this <beans profile="dev">
    <util:properties id="myproperties" 
                     location="WEB-INF/dev.properties" />
</beans>

<beans profile="qa">
    <util:properties id="myproperties" 
                     location="WEB-INF/qa.properties" />
</beans>  at the end, thats depends on how are you reading the properties

Comment: Thanks! it helps a lot!