# Spring @Value NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an Integer autowired in constructor like that:

```
@Value("${application.someNumber:0}") Integer number)
```

And there is NullPointerException if nmber is null in configuration. How to write this expression so that if it is null then it would be set to 0 ? Then I would throw my own validation expetion somewhere else.. ?

Comment: it does set default value if not present isn't it? or i dont get the question

Comment: Worth taking a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143562/using-value-with-condition-in-spring-in-order-to-map-value-to-string

Comment: Is `)` at the end typo? Update the question with a larger code snippet.

Comment: Can you please post your stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `@Value` annotation in the constructor, you must annotate the constructor itself with `@Autowired`. Also the class must be a spring managed bean (component, service...)

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the `)` at the end. As for your question. You can simply assign 0 to `number` like so:

`Integer number = 0;`

When the injected value is null `number` will keep the original value of `0`, if it is not null it will get the injected value

Comment: But it is injected in constructor so I cannot assign 0

Comment: then in the body of the constructor you add the following: `if (number == null) number = 0;`